# Who does this sentence refer to? お前、あたしたちのこと、認めてくれたんだよな？

Tags: meaning

> ――いいよな、さくら…？
>
> お前、あたしたちのこと、認めてくれたんだよな？
>
> だから、何も問題なんかないよな…？

My translation:

> This is fine, right Sakura...?
>
> You've already acknowledged us, right?
>
> So, you won't have a problem with this, right...?

Regarding the second sentence to whom does it refer? Who is being acknowledged? Is my translation accurate?

Context: It is a monologue from Susan. Sakura told Susan to be best friends. Both Susan and Sakura are in love with the same guy and Susan starts going out with that boy. Sakura had accepted it.

Comment: It's tricky because the lack of some particles, since it's casual speech, i'm not 100% sure so I won't answer. But for me, it feels like you're right

Comment: I believe Susan is a name for a girl, but the monologue is spoken by a male speaker. This makes me feel weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say  あたしたちのこと - "the thing about us" - refers to the relationship between Susan, the speaker, and the boy she and Sakura are both in love with, and 認める here is best translated as "accept". Susan is asking Sakura to reassure her that she's resigned to the fact that the young man they both like prefers Susan. How about something like:

You're OK with this, right, Sakura?

You've accepted that X and I are together now, right?

So there won't be a problem or anything, right?

Comment: My doubt is whether  あたしたちのこと could be referring to Susan and Sakura, who had become best friends the previous night. You sure it refers to Susan and the boy?

Comment: The other possibility would be (from the context given) that  あたしたち means "you and me", but I think it's more likely, given that she uses  認める , "recognise", "accept", "acknowledge", that she's talking about a relationship that doesn't include Sakura. Is there anything in what follows that suggests she means something like "You've acknowledged that the relationship between you and me has changed"?

Comment: Both girls slept in the same futon the night before (nothing weird, just cuddling) when they went on a trip together. That was when Sakura made Susan promise they will always be best friends. But the day after Susan went after the boy and she's kissing  him while she monologues. Both girls atmitted to loving the same guy while they were in the same futon. Susan actually asked why Sakura wasn't fighting for him and Sakura said because the best relationship is that in which 2 people that love each other the most are together, and she wasn't so serious about him.

Comment: 2 months later Sakura realizes she loves him just as much as Susan and she sleeps with the boy and does all sorts of things to him. The boy is easy prey for her charms.

Comment: Wow! A pretty complicated relationship among the three of them! Sounds like an exciting book. SW thinks the speaker is male, but doesn't the use of あたしたち  pretty much rule this out? It'm

Comment: Sorry - I accidentally sent before I'd finished. I think it's more likely that two young women in a close relationship would use informal "male" speech than that a man would say  あたし. My feeling is still that Susan is wanting to be reassured that her relationship with the boy X won't undermine her relationship with Sakura.

Comment: It is most certainly a girl (Susan). All 3 of them were great friends before. In the end the girls stop being friends (because of all the backstabbing). Last question: what does your gut tell you? あたしたちのこと refers to all 3 of them, to both girls or to the boy and the girl (accepting their relationship). As I said Susan was kissing the bot while monologuing.

Comment: My gut feeling is still that Susan is talking about her relationship with the boy X and wants Sakura to assure her that she's OK with it. How does Sakura actually respond to this speech by Susan?

Comment: Actually it's just monologue. Susan is kissing the boy while she thinks that. Sakura is somewhere else.